# Calling controller action from another controller action

Tags: php, zend-framework, model-view-controller

I'm new to php mvc, would like to know if it is make sense to call to controller from another controller.

Reason is I've action that should be launched upon some button A is pressed.
When I press on button B I want to do some new logic and in addition the same logic which is being launched after button A is pressed.

Comment: You can do that, that does not break your MVC implementation, you can also extract it from your controller into a helper or a model class, and use that in your two controllers, will be cleaner that way.

Comment: Great now in the same issue, is it true that logic should take place in model rather than in controller class.